# How to plot a queue of points?

Tags: python, matplotlib, queue

I have the following code.

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
plt.ion()
plt.show()

mapping = defaultdict(partial(deque, maxlen=10))
```

My mapping structure contains a queues with x, y, z values. I want to plot only the point in queue so as the queue changes the plot should also change. How would I do that?

**Note:** This is challenging because the queue is of a bounded size and the plot has to reflect only whats in the queue.

Comment: Are you asking how to get data out of your data-structures or what to do with them once you have it?  Once you have the data `ax.plot(x,y,z)` [doc](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.Axes3D.plot).

Comment: @tcaswell I'm not sure how to explain it any simpler. I have points in a bounded queue and I want my plot to reflect what I have in the queue. As the queue changes the plot should also change.

Comment: Do you have a call back or any way to signal when the data is the queue changes?  You should make it clearer in your question that you want the plot to reflect updates to the data.

Comment: @tcaswell I edit the question, I hope it's clearer. I know when the queue changes but I have no idea how to tell the plot to remove an old point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hacky way to do this is:

```
ln, = ax.plot(x,y,z)
# some code that updates the x,y,z values -> new_x,new_y,new_z
ln.remove
ln, = ax.plot(new_x,new_y,new_z)
plt.draw()
```

which removes the line with the old data and adds one with the new data.

If you are willing to write code that depends on the internals of `matplotlib` (which is a bad idea as the internal will likely change under you), you can also do this by:

```
ln._verts3d = new_x,new_y,new_z
```

Patch here for added a function to do this: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/1629

The [animation](http://matplotlib.org/api/animation_api.html) module nicely wraps up many of the things needed to do animation (including a way to stream output directly to ffmpeg), and there is a very nice [tutorial](http://jakevdp.github.com/blog/2012/08/18/matplotlib-animation-tutorial/).

[`Line3D` docs](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/api.html#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d.Line3D), [`Line2D` docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/artist_api.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D)

Comment: Thanks this solution worked but it seems `matplotlib` is not really for animation which is what I'm essentially doing.

Comment: @ahenderson I have had pretty good success with animating things with `matplotlib` (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YJuFxZRgIMk ).  You should look into the `animation` module of `matplotlib` (see edit).